# Удаление ребра в графе и поиск пути

Tags: c++, графы, dfs

У меня есть неориентированный граф состоящий из n вершин и n ребёр. Мне нужно быстро отвечать на запрос, существует ли путь из точки А в точку В, если я удалю определённое ребро из точки А.

Сначала я написал простенький DFS, который запускается из точки А и ищет путь в точку В. Но когда мне нужно было искать путь из нескольких точек в точку В (при том что у каждой точки я удаляю ребро и пытаюсь найти путь), я понял, что это работает слишком долго.

У меня уже есть некоторые представления об этом графе, например, я знаю, что это дерево с одним дополнительным ребром. Правда мне это никак не помогает и у меня совершенно нет идей как быстро искать существование пути.

Можете дать подсказки? Хотя бы тему, которую стоит лучше изучить.

Comment: ` n вершин и n ребёр` Число ребер всегда равно числу вершин в исходном графе? Не опечатка?

Comment: Нет, именно что n вершин и n рёбер, то есть это дерево, к которому добавили ещё одно ребро.

Comment: @Отчаявшийсячел, ребро соединяет вершины. Или у вас ребро в никуда?

Comment: @megorit Ребро всегда соединяет две вершины, после удаления ребра может остаться одинокая вершина. А и В не могут совпадать.

Comment: У вас данные приходят одним пакетом? Т.е "граф+ребро для удаления + две вершины"  или  сперва "граф", потом много запросов типа "реббро для удаления + 2 вершины"? Можно ли сделать предварительные вычисления ?

Comment: точную формулировку задачи можно? В целом нужно  уметь быстро отвечать принадлежит ли вершина поддереву или нет. можно даже о наименьшем общем предке задуматься.